# How to apply rules depending on environment on .eslintrc.cjs

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vite

I am using Vite and Vue3, and I am trying to apply eslint rules depending on the environment on .eslintrc.cjs

I am using vite and when I added like this

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended', 'prettier'],
    plugins: ['prettier'],
    rules: {
        'no-console': import.meta.env.PROD ? 'error' : 'off'
    },
};
```

but gets error as

> Error: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

How can I make this work? Also, is applying a rule like this even epossible?

Comment: module.exports and .cjs indicate that it's commonjs module, it's incorrect to use import there. It's unlikely that eslint runs through vite, so it doesn't make sense to use vite-specific vars there. But it runs in node, so the env should be available as process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: I was having process.env.NODE_ENV before migrating to vue 3 and vite, and needed to change environment variable to import.meta..... Is it correct to keep process.env.NODE_ENV only in eslintrc.config?

Comment: Yes. It's good to understand where these env vars come from. eslint is Node app and has  process.env.NODE_ENV natively. I suppose you used Vue CLI before. It injected NODE_ENV to client-side apps because there's no `process` in browsers. Same for Vite. eslint is not a part of client-side app and so isn't affected by Vite

Comment: @EstusFlask I would like to choose you as a best answer, if you have time please post your answer and will check it. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: @EstusFlask I used process.env.NODE_ENV in eslintrc.js and it says process is undefined. I'm using Vite with Vue3

Comment: @Seangle It's unknown at which point the error occurs and what's "it"; could be IDE problem, for instance. I don't see how it's possible with eslint alone. It's Node process and always has `process` variable. If the problem persists, consider asking a question that applies to your case